# How do mock asynchronous methods that are called multiple times with different parameters in Jasmine/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have testing a controller method that loops over an asynchronous method. If the method was only called once, I would create a spy and return the pertinent data. However, the async method needs to be called multiple times. For my test, I want to loop over the method twice and resolve the promise with different data for each iteration.

```
# coffeescript
for i in set
  mySvc.myAsyncMethod id
  .then (results) ->
     # do stuff
```